# Estimate error of distance measurement of the distance sensor

Tags: c, arduino

hint: keep sensor at constant distance from the obstacle. Take multiple dis-
tance measurements. Find minimum, maximum and average values of the
measurements.

Comment: And your question is...?

Answer (score 0):

So without knowing anything at all about your application and shooting blindly:

1. Allocate a buffer to store your sensor readings.
2. Sample your ADC module that is hooked up to your sensor and load values into buffer.
3. Loop through buffer, find min, max, calculate average with a simple for statement...

Help us, help you. A little more detail would go a long way.